# Angular ng-messages require error inside UI Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-messages

Im trying to use ng-messages for UI validation feedback inside a UI Bootstrap modal. (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Every time the modal is opened I get this error.

```
[$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!
```

Everything is setup right as said here(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages). All angularjs files are referenced, the messages module dependency is added to the main module and the directive is used as it should but I still get this error.
It happens if I use both ng-message or ng-messages-include.

Here's my modal's HTML content template:

```
<form name="formTrocaDeSenha" data-ng-submit="vm.submit(formTrocaDeSenha.$valid)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Senha atual:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="senhaAntiga" class="form-control" style="width: 256px" data-ng-model="vm.senhaAntiga" required minlength="8" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="formTrocaDeSenha.senhaAntiga.$error"></div> 
        <!--data-ng-messages-include="/app/mensagensValidacao.html"></div>-->
        <div ng-message="required">Campo obrigatório</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Mínimo de 8 caracteres</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" type="button" data-ng-click="vm.cancelar()">Cancelar</button>
    <br />
    <div style="width:50%" data-ng-show="vm.message != ''" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.message}}</div>
</form>
```

I checked the messges-include directive and it already trys to find the controller in parent scope:

```
.directive('ngMessagesInclude',['$templateRequest', '$document', '$compile', function($templateRequest, $document, $compile) {
     return {
         restrict: 'AE',
         require: '^^ngMessages', // we only require this for validation sake
         link: function($scope, element, attrs) {}
     }
 };
```

Heres a plunk from Scott Allen that I took as a guide that works just fine: /FipgiTUaaymm5Mk6HIfn (I can't post more then 2 links)

I guess it's something with the modal.
Anyone have an idea of what can be leading to this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've closed the tag with the `ng-messages` directive before declaring your tags with the `ng-message` directive:

```
<div ng-messages="formTrocaDeSenha.senhaAntiga.$error"></div>
<div ng-message="required">Campo obrigatório</div>
<div ng-message="minlength">Mínimo de 8 caracteres</div>
```

You're supposed to nest them, the correct way:

```
<div ng-messages="formTrocaDeSenha.senhaAntiga.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Campo obrigatório</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Mínimo de 8 caracteres</div>
</div>
```

Knowing that, i bet the error message makes more sense now ;)

> Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!

Comment: You're right, that worked both for defining messages right below the ng-messages and also for the ng-messages-include.

But I still dont know why it does not work like on this plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/FipgiTUaaymm5Mk6HIfn) where he uses the ng-messages-include attribute within the same div.
If I do the same I still get the require error.

Comment: I can't answer, specifically, why that plunker code does not work, but I do not see that style of usage in the Angular ng-message docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages which shows a nesting, similar to the answer above, of a div with ng-messages-include attribute *inside* a div with an ng-messages attribute.

It's possible that plunker displays an older style of declaration that worked in the past but fails now.

Comment: I got the same problem with you when using the ng-messages inside the modal box. If I use outside, I can see it work. Any idea?